# How to skip missing files when downloading multiples files from the web?

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a question about downloading files. I know how to download files, using the `download.file` function. I need to download multiple files from a particular site, each file corresponding to a different date. I have a series of dates, using which I can prepare the URL to download the file. I know for a fact that for some particular dates, the files are missing on the website. Subsequently my code stops at that point. I then have to manually reset the date index (increment it by 1) and re-run the code. Since I have to download more than 1500 files, I was wondering if I can somehow capture the 'absence of the file' and instead of the code stopping, it continues with the next date in the array.

Below is the dput of a part of the date array:

```
dput(head(fnames,10))
c("20060102.trd", "20060103.trd", "20060104.trd", "20060105.trd", 
"20060106.trd", "20060109.trd", "20060110.trd", "20060112.trd", 
"20060113.trd", "20060116.trd")
```

This file has 1723 dates. Below is the code that I am using:

```
for (i in 1:length(fnames)){
file <- paste(substr(fnames[i],7,8), substr(fnames[i],5,6), substr(fnames[i],1,4), sep = "")
URL <- paste("http://xxxxx_",file,".zip",sep="")
download.file(URL, paste(file, "zip", sep = "."))
unzip(paste(file, "zip", sep = "."))}
```

The program works fine, till it encounters a particular date for which the file is missing, and it stops. Is there a way to capture this, and print the missing file name (the variable 'file'), and move on to the next date in the array?

Please help.

I apologize that I have not shared the exact URL. In case it becomes difficult to simulate the issue, then please let me know.

***** Trying to incorporate @Paul's suggestion.

I worked on a smaller dataset.

> dput(testnames) is 
>       c("20120214.trd", "20120215.trd", "20120216.trd", "20120217.trd", 
>       "20120221.trd")

I know that file corresponding to the date '20120216' is missing from the website. I altered my code to incorporate the tryCatch function. Below it is:

```
tryCatch({for (i in 1:length(testnames)){
        file <- paste(substr(testnames[i],7,8), substr(testnames[i],5,6), substr(testnames[i],1,4), sep = "")
        URL <- paste("http://xxxx_",file,".zip",sep="")
        download.file(URL, paste(file, "zip", sep = "."))
        unzip(paste(file, "zip", sep = "."))}
},
error = function(e) {cat(file, '\n')
                     i=i+1},
warning = function(w) {message('cannot unzip')
                       i=i+1}
)
```

It runs fine for the first two dates, and as expected, throws an error for the 3rd one. I am facing 2 issues:

1. When I 'exclude' the `warning` block, it gives me the missing file name `file` as coded in the `error` block. But when I 'include' the `warning` block, it only issues the warning, and somehow doesnt execute the `error` block.  Why is that?
2. In either case, the code stops after reading "20120216.trd" and doesnt proceed ahead with the next file, which is desirable. Is incrementing the variable `i` not sufficient for that purpose?

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `tryCatch`. This function will try the operation you feed it, and provide you with a way to dealing with errors. For example, in your case an error could simply lead to skipping the file and ignoring the error. For example:

```
skip_with_message = simpleError('Did not work out')
tryCatch(print(bla), error = function(e) skip_with_message)
# <simpleError: Did not work out>
```

Notice that the error here is that the `bla` object does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for quick solution @Paul. I tried working on it, but am still facing issues. Would you please have a look at the edit that I have made.

Comment: The `tryCatch` needs to be inside the for loop, not outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul. It worked. It seems the thing to do now that you have pointed it out :) Thanks again!